# Issue with referencing Winform form

Tags: c#, winforms, class, program-entry-point

I have bean having a issue referencing a winform form I initialize in main, the code for the referencing is as follows,

```
Form1 f1 = new Form1();
Application.Run(f1);
f1.changeText("Hello World");
```

the form itself is defined in another file. f1.changetext is a simple function which takes a string input and sets a text block element to the string, I call the function in the form class as the result of clicking a button and that works fine but when I call it in main I get no result. As a side note I have a console.writeline function in main as well that doesn't do anything but I don't know if that's related. For context I'm using Visual studio and if it wasn't obvious I don't have too much experience with coding with classes and frameworks like this. Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: `Application.Run` is a blocking call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `Application.Run(f1);` also shouldnt you **change the text prior to "Running it**?"

It Being:

```
Form1 f1 = new Form1();
f1.changeText("Hello World");
Application.Run(f1);
```

A way I'm sure will work (the one I use) with showing / initializing another form would be

```
Form1 f1 = new Form1();
f1.changeText("Hello World");
f1.ShowDialog();
```

Have you tried Debug to check if the code works / was read when running?

Comment: You know I think I was thinking in terms of unity(where all my experience comes from) where you had to initialize the object before altering it, and after testing it out you are correct! Thanks a bunch

Comment: 'Form1 f1 = new Form1();' Would be the Initialization no?  You need to change before showing the Form, because once you "enter" the form, the 'f1.changeText("Hello World");' would only be run after said form was closed